# Generating a xsd from an xml

Tags: offline, xml

I would like to generate the xsd of an existing xml file.
I found tools such as [this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html), but no offline tool. This is a problem since for privacy reasons, I don't want to send the data to an external server.

As a consequence, I'm looking for an software with the following caracteristics :

- able to generate a xsd from a xml file
- available offline on windows 8
- open-source with a license enabling commercial use of generated schemas.

Comment: Normally you would generate the XSD from the Schemas that is referenced in the XML file rather than from the XML file itself.

Comment: @SteveBarnes I agree. However, the schema (if it ever was done) is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Trang, it satisfies all your requirements, here is the project url:

http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html

Here is the example of generating shema for test.xml:

```
java -jar trang.jar -I xml -O xsd test.xml test.xsd
```

There is a other free soulutions but not open source, like MS xsd.exe that comes with Visual Studio, there is a standalone version that you can download from [here](http://juliankay.com/development/download-xsd-exe/).

And my personal favorite way Liquid XML Studio, there is no free edition anymore but you can download old [Liquid XML Studio 2009 Community Edition](http://www.tucows.com/preview/516325/Liquid-XML-Studio-2009)